# How to adapt query to API?

Tags: graphql

I'm trying to wrap my head around GraphQL.

Right now I'm just playing with the public API of Artsy (an art website, playground at https://metaphysics-production.artsy.net). What I want to achieve is following:

1. I want to get all node types `entities` without declaring them by hand (is there a shortcut for this)?
2. I want every node with a field `type` from which I can read the type, without parsing through `imageUrl` etc. to fint that out.

What I constructed as of right now is this:

```
{
  search(query: "Berlin", first: 100, page: 1, entities: [ARTIST, ARTWORK, ARTICLE]) {
  edges {
    node {
      displayLabel
      imageUrl
      href
    }
  }
}}
```

Very primitive I guess. Can you guys help me?

Comment: What are you using to create this query? Is it generated using code? Or are you just using their playground?

Comment: Mix of both, this playground offers auto complete.

Comment: See my answer below

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR**:

1) There is no shortcut, it's not something GraphQL offers out of the box. Nor is it something I was able to find via their Schema.

2) Their returned `node` of type `Searchable` does not contain a property for `type` that you're looking for. But you can access it via the `... on SearchableItem` [(union) syntax](https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#union-types).

---

**Explanation**:

For question 1):

Looking at their schema, you can see that their search query has the following type details:

```
search(
  query: String!
  entities: [SearchEntity]
  mode: SearchMode
  aggregations: [SearchAggregation]
  page: Int
  after: String
  first: Int
  before: String
  last: Int
): SearchableConnection
```

The query accepts an `entities` property of type `SearchEntity` which looks like this:

```
enum SearchEntity {
  ARTIST
  ARTWORK
  ARTICLE
  CITY
  COLLECTION
  FAIR
  FEATURE
  GALLERY
  GENE
  INSTITUTION
  PROFILE
  SALE
  SHOW
  TAG
}
```

Depending on what your usecase is, if you're constructing this query via some code, then you can find out which `SearchEntity` values they have:

```
{
  __type(name: "SearchEntity") {
    name
    enumValues {
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
  "data": {
    "__type": {
      "name": "SearchEntity",
      "enumValues": [
        {
          "name": "ARTIST"
        },
        {
          "name": "ARTWORK"
        },

      ...

    }
  }
}
```

then store them in an array, **omit** the quotation marks from the enum and pass the array back to the original query directly as an argument.

Something along the lines of this:

```
query search($entities: [SearchEntity]) {
  search(query: "Berlin", first: 100, page: 1, entities: $entities) {
    edges {
    node {
      displayLabel
      imageUrl
      href
    }
  }
 }
}
```

and in your query variables section, you just need to add:

```
{
  "entities": [ARTIST, ARTWORK, ...]
}
```

As for question 2)

The query itself returns a `SearchableConnection` object.

```
type SearchableConnection {
  pageInfo: PageInfo!
  edges: [SearchableEdge]
  pageCursors: PageCursors
  totalCount: Int
  aggregations: [SearchAggregationResults]
}
```

Digging deeper, we can see that they have `edges`, of type `SearchableEdge` - which is what you're querying.

```
type SearchableEdge {
  node: Searchable
  cursor: String!
}
```

and finally, `node` of type `Searchable` which contains the data you're trying to access.

Now, the type `Searchable` doesn't contain `type`:

```
type Searchable {
  displayLabel: String
  imageUrl: String
  href: String
}
```

But, if you look at where that `Searchable` type is implemented, you can see `SearchableItem` - which contains the property of `displayType` - which doesn't actually exist in `Searchable`.

You can access the property of `SearchableItem` and get the `displayType`, like so:

```
{
  search(query: "Berlin", first: 100, page: 1, entities: [ARTIST, ARTWORK, ARTICLE]) {
    edges {
      node {
        displayLabel
        imageUrl
        href
        ... on SearchableItem {
          displayType
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and your result will look like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "search": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "displayLabel": "Boris Berlin",
            "imageUrl": "https://d32dm0rphc51dk.cloudfront.net/CRxSPNyhHKDIonwLKIVmIA/square.jpg",
            "href": "/artist/boris-berlin",
            "displayType": "Artist"
          }
        },

...
```